# Compile time object list

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is there any way to create a compile time list of all those compenents? They are known at compile time so I guess it is possible. In the ideal case I would like to achieve unrolled loop, equivalent of this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "first" << '\n';
  std::cout << "second" << '\n';
  std::cout << "third" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

That's the code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<size_t N>
struct fixed_string {
  constexpr fixed_string(const char(&string)[N]) {
    std::copy_n(string, N, data);
  }

  char data[N];
};


class base_component {
public:
  static inline std::list<base_component*> all_components;

  virtual const char* get_name() = 0;
};


template <fixed_string name>
class component : public base_component {
public:
  component() {
    all_components.push_back(this);
  }

  virtual const char* get_name() {
    return name.data;
  }
};


static component<"first"> first;
static component<"second"> second;
static component<"third"> third;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for (auto object : base_component::all_components) {
    std::cout << object->get_name() << '\n';
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some `std::tuple<...types>` maybe?

Comment: I'm not certain that the fully unrolled loop is feasible. What if there are `component` declarations in other compilation units, which are not available to the linker until after `main` has been compiled?

Comment: No, it is *not* possible to just collect a bunch of static variables into a container known at compile time. As you noticed, you have been using the constructors to "self-register" which simply won't work at all at compile time. You would need to create a container holding all these explicitly. At most, you could use macro magic to build that list as you create the definitions.

Comment: You *must* know the size of the container at compile-time for this to work. Even a "max" size would help. Then you'd have to bite the bullet and track an index variable to and from each instantiation of a component (then it's up to you to ensure nobody uses the same index)